# /1.#IND error in ERDAS

Tags: error, erdas-imagine

I was applying the vegetation index 
`($n1_ttc0003r_16(2) - $n1_ttc0003r_16(4)) / ($n1_ttc0003r_16(2) + $n1_ttc0003r_16(4))`
to a multispectral image, and the raster resulting on this operation had all its values equal to `-1.#IND`. Can anyone help me understanding what's happening? I think this means that some pixel values of the output raster are the result of a division by zero. How can I solve this?